# Require Only One Of Multiple Columns Be Not Null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for the badly-worded title, but my inability to express exactly what I mean is probably why I can't find anything relating to this with Google.

Simply put, imagine a situation where you have table named Image in a database which holds pictures and related metadata.  The photo could be of a client, of their car or of a particular repair being carried out on the car.  There are tables called Client, Car and Repair, each with their own unique ID column.

In the Image table, there is a column named ClientID, a column named CarID and a column named RepairID, which links each image record to a client, car and/or repair.  The problem is, an image might relate to a client AND a car but not a repair, or a car and repair but not a client, or only one of any of those three.  In other words, there might be a value in one, two or three of the columns, but there MUST be a column in AT LEAST ONE.  As long as one is not NULL, the other two can be.

Is there a way to achieve this with constraints (or any other method) in MSSQL?

Hopefully the example diagram below will illustrate what I'm talking about.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a constraint on the `Image` table that looks like this:

```
Car is not null or Client is not null or Repair is not null
```

DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Image]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Image_CarClientRepair] CHECK  (Car is not null or Client is not null or Repair is not null)
```

Comment: That looks simple enough! Are you aware of any particular performance issues this might create?

Comment: There would be virtually no overhead with this, it is a trivial check.