# Require One of Multiple Foreign Keys in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm basically trying to enforce this in Entity Framework: [Require Only One Of Multiple Columns Be Not Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144846/require-only-one-of-multiple-columns-be-not-null)

My database has several 1:m relationships where the child entity belongs to one of several parent entities. For example, let's say I have tables for `Teachers`, `Students`, and `Guardians`. Each of those can have many `PhoneNumbers` and `EmailAddresses`. I am using EF Code First, and my models look something like:

```
public class Teacher {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Student {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Guardian {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the migration, this creates the database with the tables/columns I would expect. The `PhoneNumbers` and `EmailAddresses` tables each have columns `Teacher_Id`, `Student_Id`, and `Guardian_Id`, which are foreign keys to their respective parent entity. However, there are no constraints on how many parent entities can be set on the child. For example, I can create a `PhoneNumber` that has all three parent IDs set to null, or I can set both a `Teacher_Id` and a `Guardian_Id`.

I tried adding a required attribute to the parents like so:

```
public class Teacher { // Also Student/Guardian
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

That does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do this on entities. Instead, create a migration and try to alter the table in migration class like this:

```
    public partial class YourMigrationName: Migration
                            {
                              protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
                                {
                                    migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PhoneNumber]  
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_PhoneNumer_Teacher_Student_Guardian] CHECK  (Teacher_Id
 is not null or Student_Id is not null or Guardian_Id is not null)
                            GO
                            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmailAddress]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
            [CK_EmailAddress_Teacher_Student_Guardian] CHECK  (Teacher_Id is not null or 
        Student_Id is not null or Guardian_Id is not null)
                        ");
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class PhoneNumber 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    //Added this code:
    [Required] 
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set;}
}

public class EmailAddress {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //Added this code:  
    [Required]
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set;}
}
```

That would make sure you cannot create PhoneNumber without Teacher. You can also do this:

```
public class PhoneNumber 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int TeacherId
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set;}
}
```

That would also detect that you want to add constraint on your PhoneNumber. Both ways work fine.

Comment: PhoneNumber and EmailAddress can belong to a Teacher, Student, or Guardian. I can't make all three required, as each email/number can only belong to one.

Comment: If that's the case, you will need to add constraint based on the answer that you shared on your link. Or the answer before me. You can also write custom model validation attribute as well.